# How to take pictures of the video through mplayer or ffmpeg to php?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, image, mplayer

How to take pictures of the video through mplayer or ffmpeg to php?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? EDIT: a lot more specific.

Comment: For example there is a video with a size of 5 minutes. And I need to take a screenshot of the example of exactly 2 nd minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

> exec("ffmpeg -i $video_file_path -an
>   -y -f mjpeg -ss 00:02:00 -vframes 1 $image_path")

Comment: And through mplayer know how?

Comment: @Zhasulan: Well, i have not used mplayer yet, but quick googling gave me this link, http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/479575-how-capture-images-video. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ffmpeg is installed on your server, you can use the following code to output the frame at exactly 2 minutes to a JPEG file:

```
function vidtojpeg($video_filename, $dimensions) {
    exec("ffmpeg -i $video_filename -an -ss 00:01:59 -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -s $dimensions video%d.jpg");
}
```

In this function, the $video_filename parameter is self-explanatory. The $dimensions parameter accepts width and height of the outputted images in this format: WIDTHxHEIGHT. For example: 320x480 would be an acceptable parameter.

Comment: And through mplayer know how?

Comment: No, sorry. Do you absolutely need solutions for FFmpeg and Mplayer?

Answer (score 1):

Converting the video to frames and getting the required frames based on timings can help. Try this : `ffmpeg -i video.flv -r 25 -vcodec png -pix_fmt rgb32 %d.png`

You can manipulate the formats and bitrate(-r) for getting the required frame in proper format.